# Python etree xml write issues

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to write multiple files to a directory with very little changed in between each file (eg. incremental id numbers) When I try run my program, it fails after writing about 5 files.  But when I try it again and re-select the source file, it works.  Here's my code:

```
if not os.path.isdir(self.fDirectory + "/AutoGen" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",           gmtime())):
        os.mkdir(self.fDirectory + "/AutoGen" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S", gmtime()))

    anum = 0
    for x in range(len(self.csvdata)-1):
        for y in range(len(self.csvdata[x+1])):
            self.myRoot.find(self.csvdata[0][y]).text = self.csvdata[x][y]
        anum+=1
        myTree.write(self.fDirectory + "/AutoGen" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S", gmtime()) + "/" + self.filename + "_" + str(anum) + ".xml")
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1399, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\CNash\Documents\XML Generator\XMLGen.py", line 148, in doIt
myTree.write(self.fDirectory + "/AutoGen" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S", gmtime()) + "/" + self.filename + "_" + str(anum) + ".xml")
File "C:\Python32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 836, in write
file = open(file_or_filename, "wb")
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/CNash/Documents/XML Generator/AutoGen2012-07-31_20.23.52/EXuTest_DOCD00140_6.xml'
```

Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry but this has nothing to do with etree or xml.  You seemingly have not supplied the correct path for python to write to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join), it will make your life easier.

And it looks to me that the first and last calls to `strftime` happen at different times (and you left out an underscore in your first one). The script can't find the directory, because it doesn't exist. One named with a time a few seconds before probably, *even suspiciously*, does, I bet.

Try replacing your first `if`-statement with

```
dirname = os.path.join(self.fDirectory,strftime("AutoGen%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S",gmtime()))

if not os.path.isdir(dirname):
    os.mkdir(dirname)
```

and the last line with:

```
myTree.write(os.path.join(dirname, self.filename + "_" + str(anum) + ".xml"))
```

Comment: Thanks.  That makes complete sense and I thought it might have something to do with that, but didn't know enough to figure it out.  Added ")" at the end of your code and your strftime needed periods, not semi-colons to match windows path convention.  Now it seems to be working perfectly!